# Android - How to disable QR Code scanning in ZXing Library and allow only Bar code scaning

Tags: android, zxing, barcode-scanner

I want to give 2 options in My Code for Zxing Bar scanning.

**Options:**

1. Scan Bar Code
2. Scan QR Code.

After selecting first option only Bar-Code should get scan by ZXing Library and same for option two.

Please help me with the code if any flag is there in Zxing to enable and disable.

Comment: Have u tried any thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested its working for me

**For QR code scan use**

```
  IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
  integrator.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.QR_CODE_TYPES);
  integrator.setPrompt("Scan a Qr code");
  integrator.setCameraId(0);  // Use a specific camera of the device
  integrator.setBeepEnabled(false);
  integrator.setBarcodeImageEnabled(true);
  integrator.initiateScan();
```

**and for bar code use**

```
    IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
    integrator.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.ONE_D_CODE_TYPES);
    integrator.setPrompt("Scan a barcode");
    integrator.setCameraId(0);  // Use a specific camera of the device
    integrator.setBeepEnabled(false);
    integrator.setBarcodeImageEnabled(true);
    integrator.initiateScan();
```

Comment: Thank You buddy , But I'm not using  IntentIntegrator

Answer (score 2):

For scanning QR Code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
```

For scanning bar code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "PRODUCT_MODE");
```

Comment: I am using Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE"); but still i can able to capture bar code.